# JQuery 1.9 not triggering setData event

Tags: jquery, events, bind

The following code works in JQuery 1.8 but not in JQuery 1.9

```
<div id="time" class="updateTime"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#time').on('setData', function(evt, key, value) {
    if ( key == 'clock' ) {
        $(this).html( value );
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    var time = (new Date()).toString();
    $('#time').data('clock', time );    
}, 1000);

});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sz7qh/)

anyone please explain me

Comment: is there any syntax change in 1.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11718:

> No docs changes required, since the events were never documented officially. Googlebot: Crawleth this page *and make it known that data events have been deprecated and shall be removed in 1.9*.

Here's a possible patch (rather untested):

```
(function () {
    var olddata = $.fn.data;
    $.fn.data = function (key, value) {
        olddata.call(this, arguments);
        if (value !== undefined) $(this).trigger('setData', [key, value]);
    };
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pufru/

Comment: @Sajir `$('#time').html( time );` I think this is simple enough.

Comment: Use `$('#time').trigger('setData', ...)` after setting the data (or monkey patch/duck punch `$.fn.data` as suggested in the link).