# Set handler for change event on a DOM element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I would like to run a function every time a specific DOM element is manipulated.

Example:

I manipulate the `data-expertize` attribute of an element having the class `.milestones-chain`:

```
$(".milestones-chain").data("expertizes","<%= @challenge.root.expertizes %>");
```

I would like this to trigger a function automatically.

I tried this:

```
$(document).on('change','.milestones-chain', function() {
    alert("trigger my function");
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: by changing the data-* attribute it does not mean that you have changed the value of element

Comment: I didn't say that, did I?  I now that on('change' is the problem. That's why I need help...

Comment: Seems like a rude response to someone trying to help

Comment: here you can find some answers about this subject [Detect element content changes with jQuery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: @ndemoreau then you will either need timed function which call themselves automatically or why don't you call the function manually after changing the data attribute

Comment: What kind of a DOM element are we dealing with here? Select, input, div?

Comment: @ankit the idea is to have the equivalent of an after_update callback. As my element can be modified through different ways, I think it would be safer to have this kind of callback rather than calling the functions manually every time. I don't think timed function would work as it should be triggered instantly after my manipulation. Thx for you help! ;-)

Comment: @kushyar: a div element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MyBMw/)** (with version 1.8.3)

**Before** jQuery 1.9, there are event handlers for working with `data`:

- `setData` - fired whenever setting a data
- `getData` - fired whenever getting a data

However there are no documents in jQuery site, and it's removed from jQuery 1.9.

```
$(function () {
    $('.milestones-chain').on('setData', function (e, k, v) {
        alert('[CHANGED] ' + k + ' : ' + v);
    });

    $('.milestones-chain').data('expertizes', '12345');
});
```

If you run this code by jQuery 1.8, you get the `alert`.
The event fired by setting a `data` to the element. Btw, it won't work with jQuery 1.9 and upper.

---

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MyBMw/1/)** (with version 1.10.1)

You can take this feature back to new versions of jQuery.
*(I take it from this question: [JQuery 1.9 not triggering setData event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15355974/1823761)).*

```
(function () {
    var olddata = $.fn.data;
    $.fn.data = function (key, value) {
        olddata.call(this, arguments);
        if (value !== undefined) $(this).trigger('setData', [key, value]);
    };
})();
```

Just add it at the first line of your script.

Comment: I'm running 1.7.2 and it doesn't seem to work. This was THE solution however. too bad that it has been deprecated in 1.9...

Comment: @ndemoreau It works with version 1.7.2 too, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyBMw/2/). I think that this event, doesn't support **event delegation**, you must attach it directly to the element.